# Where can I find the Jenkins webserver logs on RedHat

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins webpage has been slow to respond (almost unusable), so I don't have access to the UI to pull out the logs.

Can I see the web requests from the hosting server (to detect a DOS attack for example or just to check how many people are visiting the Jenkins page)?

I checked under `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` but that seems to display only Jenkins activities (not the webserver).

Comment: I guess that is not enabled by default.  You need to try : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Access+Logging

Comment: Other choices are standard os tools (netstat, strace etc -- )

Answer (score 0):

http://Jenkins_Master:port/log

You can also add more logging. 
Either way take a look here : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging